# How to get extra columns in group by in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-annotate

I just want to include `ID`(and other fields) as well in the result of an annotate with values (i.e group by).

I'll explain with an example (below is just an example, please suspend your disbelief on this bad model),

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    version = models.IntegerField() # Assming its just a number that increments when each version is published like 1...2...3 and so on.
    published_on = models.DateTimeField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Text(models.Model):
    book_text = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

What I want is the Max version(or editions) of a Book, which I achieve by

```
Book.objects.values('name', 'author').annotate(Max('version'))


**Generated SQL (MYSQL) query**:
SELECT "name",
       "author",
       Max("version") AS "version__max" 
FROM   "book" 
GROUP  BY "name",
          "author"
```

But the above result does not contain `ID` or `published_on` if I add them to values it groups by them as well, which is not what I want. I want to group by only `name` and `author`, But want other fields or at least get an ID.

```
Expected SQL:
SELECT "id",
       "published_on",
       "name",
       "author",
       Max("version") AS "version__max" 
FROM   "book" 
GROUP  BY "name",
          "author"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL you can't select fields that are not in group by statement. You should get id by an additional query, for example:

```
Book.object.filter(name=name_from_first_query, author=author_from_first_query, version=version_from_first_query
```

Of course, you must iterate over the results of your group by query.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I guess I have to use either python or Subquery... A really good explanation I found  why it is recommended to have the same fields in both select and group by is here [link](https://www.valentina-db.com/docs/dokuwiki/v5/doku.php?id=valentina:articles:sql_selecting_from_groups) ...but thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import F

Book.objects.values('name', 'author').annotate(Max('version'), id=F('id'))
```

While doing group by, in django. The sequence matters. We pass values by which we need to group_by the queryset and inside the annotate function we use F expression to add extra elements required in the result queryset. If we add `id` in values then it will be taken into account while doing group by.
Hope this clears :)

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: So this solution seems good, I also tried it before posting. But somehow it doesn't work...the `ID` gets added to the GROUP BY query and works like 
```Book.objects.values('name', 'author','id').annotate(Max('version'))```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Added explaination for better understanding :) upvote appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.objects.values('name', 'author').annotate(Max('version'), Max('id'))
```

Comment: This solution works but looks hacky but anyway...thanks.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.